# Can I order a Criteria Query by a field belonging to a fetch?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Sorting by a field belonging to a **join** works well:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
Root root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Join joinPerson = root.join("person");

criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(joinPerson.get("lastName")));
```

How can I work out something similar with a **fetch**:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
Root root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Fetch fetchPerson = root.fetch("person");

criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(fetchPerson.????));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your fetch to path, something like:

```
    Path fetchAsPath = (Path) root.fetch("person");

    fetchAsPath.get("lastName");
```